# Unexpected variable value

Tags: php

So, here's a piece of code:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    file_put_contents('output.txt','1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111',FILE_APPEND);
    $userInMysqlDatabase=true;
}           
else
{
    file_put_contents('output.txt','22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222',FILE_APPEND);
    $userInMysqlDatabase=false;
}           

file_put_contents('output.txt','$userInMysqlDataBase: '.$userInMysqlDataBase,FILE_APPEND);
```

And the content of the output file is:

`1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111$userInMysqlDataBase:`

Which I would think is impossible, but turns out it's not. What the hell?
(there is no code between the if and the file_put_contents at the end)

Comment: You think what's impossible?

Comment: A string in `'` is treated as a string literal - in this case, it's a string that happens to contain the text `$userInMysqlDataBase: `. Try swapping the single quotes in your final `file_put_contents()` to double quotes: `"$userInMysqlDataBase: ".$userInMysqlDataBase`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *impossible* ? `file_put_contents('output.txt', '$userInMysqlDataBase: ' .  ($userInMysqlDataBase ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'), FILE_APPEND);`, no?

Comment: I think he's referring to the fact that the file contains 1s, so the variable `$userInMysqlDatabase` is true, but that value is not being outputted to the file in the final call to `file_put_contents`

Comment: @andrewsi well, OP know what he is doing. String in single quotes is only marker. Look carefully.

Comment: @j08691: That I set the value of $userInMysqlDatabase to true (it seems obvious because of the 11111111s written), still in the end the value is false, as seen in the file.

Comment: @user1437649, see Arnold Daniels's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables are case sensative, so `$userInMysqlDatabase` and `$userInMysqlDataBase` are not the same. (capital B)

Comment: This might be the exact reason.

Comment: So that `$userInMysqlDataBase `is not defined or assigned any value, hence not displayed. Replace that with `$userInMysqlDatabase` and it should work

Comment: Oh, I checked if the name is the same by double clicking on it in Notepad++, but that's not case sensitive as it turns out... Thanks.